# Remove where filter from Zend DB Select

Tags: magento, zend-framework

How do I remove a where condition on a Zend_DB_Select? I've a Magento collection which I added a where condition to using the addAttributeToFilter method from Varien_Data_Collection_Db. Now I need to remove that where condition. Is this possible?

**MORE INFO**

I've a Magento widget that loads a collection based on an attribute. The widget does this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('notnull'->true));
```

The widget also adds the following filter, to limit results to products that have a name starting with a letter:

```
collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like'-> $letter.'%'));
```

However, the client's custom toolbar needs an index of ALL the products by first letter, like [A][B][C][D]...[Z], so when you click on the link, the product collection will be filtered with products starting with that first letter. The problem is that the catalog/product_list_toolbar toolbar block uses the same product collection as the parent catalog/product_list block. So the toolbar's product collection is also filtered by letter.

**WORKAROUND**

Here's my hacky solution. I added the following code to the widget using PHP's reflection:

```
$letterCollection = clone $this->_productCollection;
$letterSelect = clone $letterCollection->getSelect();
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($letterCollection);
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('_select');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
$reflectionProperty->setValue($letterCollection, $letterSelect);
$letterCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$toolbar = $this->getChild('toolbar');
$toolbar->setLetterCollection($letterCollection);

$this->_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => "$letter%"));
```

In the extended toolbar (Namespace_Module_Block_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar), I just get the unfiltered collection:

```
$collection = $this->getLetterCollection();// $this->getCollection() would be the filtered collection
```

There should really be a way to remove filter from a Magento collection.

Comment: This is a Zend Framework question. Why do I need to explain why I added a where condition to my query? It's an arbitrary where condition. I just need to know how to remove it. Giving more information doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: More context is needed here, ideas : clone it before you add the then unwanted addAttributeToFilter, or get the model back as his original state

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Not elegant but works.

Answer (score 2):

Just call [reset](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.other.reset)

`$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);`

Comment: This removes all the where conditions. I just need to remove a specific one.

Comment: You can get where part by  $where = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE), manipulate $where as you wish and then set back to select by $select->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE, $where);, but I think that it is very very ugly hack that should be used only in exceptional situations.